# If $F\subset G$ where $F$ is a closed set and $G$ is a open set, show that $m^*(G\backslash F)=m^*(G)-m^*(F)$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The exercise is:

> If $F\subset G$ where $F$ is a closed set and $G$ is a open limited set, show that $m^*(G\backslash F)=m^*(G)-m^*(F)$.

**I try solve this**:

If $G=F\dot{\cup}(G\backslash F)$, where $A\dot{\cup}B$ denotes the disjoint union of $A$ and $B$. Then, $m^*(G)=m^*(F)+G=m^*(G\backslash F)$ because $F$ and $F\backslash G$ are a disjoint union. This solve the exercise.

*However the hint given is not that way and I was unsure of solve this way.*

**The hint:**

> Apply that for each meansurable open limited set $G\backslash F$ and for each $\varepsilon>0$, there is a closed set $F_1$ that $F_1\subset (F\backslash G)$ such that $m^*(F_1)>m^*(G\backslash F)-\varepsilon$(I proved this result in the exercise before that). Show that 
>   $$
> m^*(F)+m^*(G\backslash F)<m^*(F)+m^*(F_1)+\varepsilon=m^*(F\cup F_1)+\varepsilon
> $$

**I would like to know how to use this tip and my resolution is wrong.**

Comment: You need to assume $m^*(G) < \infty$ to apply the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct but assumes measurability of $G$ and $F$. The hint avoids this.

Since $F \cup F_1 \subset G$, the hint leads to $m^*(F) + m^*(G \setminus F) < m^*(G) + \epsilon$. Since $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary this implies $m^*(F) + m^*(G \setminus F) \le m^*(G)$.

The reverse inequality is a trivial application of subadditivity.